# where to store global object in quasar framework

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, quasar-framework

I'm re-writing my old app using [Quasar Framework](https://quasar-framework.org/) which is based on [Vue](https://vuejs.org/), and I have a piece of code (class) which encapsulates websocket functionality.

It is a fairly simple concept: user travels from page to page in the app, but if he receives a message he can see a toast message/reply or a counter of `unread messages` increments.

I'm a little bit lost in the `Quasar` (`Vue`) architecture and here is my question:

**Where would I store a global object which communicates with outside world, exists as long as the application exists and accessible from anywhere?**

I read documentation of `Quasar` (`Vue`) but I still don't know where to put it. Vuex doesn't look right since it is not a state of the app. It is more like a faceless component.

Does it mean that I should use a plugin or `Vue.prototype` or a global mixin or something else?

I appreciate if someone can share their experience and a piece of code describing how to initialize and access this object's methods.

Comment: Store(Vuex) seems to be the best place for storing and maintaining such variables.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in my opinion:

**Method 1. Use quasar plugin base on Vue prototype (sure you knew it):**

plugins/foo.js

```
const fooModule = {
  a: 1,
  doTest() { console.log('doTest') }
};
export default ({Vue}) => {
  Vue.prototype.$foo = fooModule;
}
```

quasar.conf.js

```
plugins: [
  'i18n',
  'axios',
  'foo',
],
```

component `bar.vue`:

```
methods: {
   test () { this.$foo.doTest() }
}
```

**Method 2. Just use js module**

Because js module is singleton. Wherever you import a js module, it all points to the same pointer.

So just have `GlobalTest.js`:

```
export default {
  a: 1,
  inc() { this.a = this.a + 1 }
}
```

And test1.js:

```
import GlobalTest from '/path/to/GlobalTest'
console.log(GlobalTest.a); // output 1
console.log(GlobalTest.inc()); // inc
```

And test2.js:

```
import GlobalTest from '/path/to/GlobalTest'
console.log(GlobalTest.a); // Assuming this was called after test1.js: output 2
```

---

I used quasar cli but I just consider quasar as a UI lib.

--- Updated ---

> It is a fairly simple concept: user travels from page to page in the app, but if he receives a message he can see a toast message/reply or a counter of unread messages increments.

Depend on the requirements, If you need "reactive" you should use Vuex (best built-in reactive lib) + split the app state into modules, 
but I only use Vuex when I need "reactive" and avoid it when I just need to read & write the value.

Comment: @luat-nguyen-mxn0 I decided to go with plugins  so I can easily access it from anywhere

Comment: how about quasar extension?

Answer (score 1):

```
// ~/store/index.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

let store
export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  /* eslint-disable no-return-assign */
  return store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {...},
    strict: process.env.DEV
  })
}

export function ensureClientStoreExists () {
  if (process.env.SERVER) {
    return new Promise(() => { /* won't resolve */ })
  }
  if (process.env.CLIENT) {
    if (store) {
      return Promise.resolve(store)
    }
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      setTimeout(resolve) // Avoid 'Maximum call stack size exceeded'
    }).then(ensureClientStoreExists)
  }
}
```

```js
// Anywhere
import { ensureClientStoreExists } from '~/store/'

ensureClientStoreExists().then(store => {
  console.log(store.state)
  store.dispatch('XXX/YYY')
})
```